# Is a RAID1 (mirror) with 2 x 4TB drives and ZFS (through freenas) okay?

Tags: raid, raid-1, zfs, freenas, redundancy

I'm looking to create a freenas RAID1 using two 4TB drives.

It's going to be my primary location for a generic backup location (use rsnapshot for local files and keeping computer dd'd images) and I'm worried about local redundancy as I've been bitten by a backup hard drive crashing in the past (hardware failure). I already have off-site redundancy built-in with Amazon's CloudDrive.

Normally when using larger drives and not just wanting mirroring (read, RAID5[Z1] or 6[Z2]), you have to worry about the size of the drives [read/write errors](http://www.zdnet.com/article/why-raid-6-stops-working-in-2019/).

Do you need to worry about this in a mirror configuration?

Some research brings up this [forum link](https://forums.freenas.org/index.php?threads/zfs-raid-size-and-reliability-calculator.28191/) and this [calculator tool](https://jsfiddle.net/Biduleohm/paq5u7z5/1/). It's showing a MTTDL: 1.6 x 10^9 h . Changing it to 4TB in a 3 mirror configuration brings up a MTTDL: 3.2 x 10^12 h .

Are more than two drives necessary? Both numbers are absurdly large...

Comment: With RAID1 (ZFS or other) you have little to worry about as it's not dependent on parity calculations. It truly is just a mirror of the data such that if you lose one of your two disks, the other would still have all the data. You'll then have the ability to replace the failed disk with a new one and begin rebuilding the mirror with little to no downtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is a RAID1 (mirror) with 2 x 4TB drives and ZFS (through freenas) okay?

If you want to use HW or non-ZFS software RAID with ZFS on top then please choose one of them. Using both would be needlessly complex without advantages.

> Normally when using larger drives and not just wanting mirroring (read,
>   RAID5[Z1] or 6[Z2]), you have to worry about the size of the drives 
>   read/write errors.

Mostly you need to worry about read errors after you loose redundancy. This is both true for regular RAID and for ZFS, though ZFS may have multiple copies of the data. (e.g. 3 copies on two drives. IIRC you can configure that).

> Do you need to worry about this in a mirror configuration?

No. As long as you have off-site backups (and you wrote that you do) then mirrored disks (HW/SW or ZFS-RAID) are just to keep things up and running and to hopefully make downloading all data from [off-site] backup needless.

Well, that and possible speed increase. But a single modern disk seems to fill gigabit ethernet nicely, so RAID might not help in many scenarios where you use a NAS.  (Such as streaming movies or music, which seems to be main NAS usage for home situations).

> Are more than two drives necessary? Both numbers are absurdly large...

For regular home usage: Nope. If it held a critical database or a fielserver at work (where hundred of people would be stuck without work if the file server failed); maybe. Though 1 or 2 disks spare is plenty even for that.

For home usage: Use one spare at most. And Make sure your off-site backups work and are updated at least monthly. Then even if a disk fails you only have to make sure that you make an additional incremental backup. Failure of the second disk does not matter at that state.

(At least it does not matter as with regard to data loss/data safety.)

Comment: *If you want to use HW or non-ZFS software RAID with ZFS on top then please choose one of them. Using both would be needlessly complex without advantages.*  Not true at all.  Running ZFS on top of HW RAID enables easy disk changes for failed disks that don't even require logging on to the server (pop out the drive with the orange light, pop in a new drive) while still providing ZFS features like snapshots, encryption, deduplication, bit-rot detection, etc.

Comment: *And Make sure your off-site backups work and are updated at least monthly.*  A thousand times this.  **RAID (of any sort) is not a backup!**

Comment: I intend to use this setup as my local backup copy of data. The raid configuration is there to help with hardware redundancy in the event of a failure. As already mentioned, am already doing remote backups(2nd backup copy).

Comment: @AndrewHenle Aside from the additional drives (worst case two times as many are needed) imagine you have a critical pool condition (errors on both disks of a mirror, for example) - you will not get hardware notification nor will you be able to replace the disks - even four real disks (two disks for ZFS, one vdev) are useless in this case. Of course you get detection, but correction is more difficult/expensive.

Comment: @user121391 *Aside from the additional drives (worst case two times as many are needed) imagine you have a critical pool condition (errors on both disks of a mirror, for example) - you will not get hardware notification nor will you be able to replace the disks*  What do you mean by that?  Are you saying you don't get notification of failures from hardware RAID controllers, nor can you replace drives in hardware RAID controllers?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I meant ZFS notifications on the hardware side - if a bit flips, your hardware may not notice it and will not alert you, so you still need the ZFS-side alerts and notifications. Complete hardware failures are of course no problem, but if you only want to guard against them, you would not need ZFS. On the other side, if you want ZFS block-level protection, you need to manage it separately anyway, questioning the usefulness of hardware RAID beneath it.

Comment: @user121391 How often have you seen ZFS complain about bit rot?  How often have you seen a drive fail?  Not even close, is it?  Replacing a drive managed under ZFS is a pain - you not only need to physically replace the drive, you need to log onto the server as root, and run zfs command(s).  If you're managing the server remotely, that's TWO persons, one of which needs to have full sysadmin rights.  HW RAID?  Pop in a new disk, done.  One person, no root access - or even any system access at all - needed.  Apply that to hundreds if not thousands of servers and their attached disk farms.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Personally I have seen more destroyed/corrupt files than broken hard drives, but it may depend on what you value more, integrity or uptime, and how you choose your hardware. Although replacement of disks can be automated - either fully with hot spares or partial with `autoreplace=on`: `any new device, found in the same physical location as a device that previously belonged to the pool, is automatically formatted and replaced`. No system access needed. Also it is possible to use 3rd-party tools like `sas2ircu` to find the right bay and flash the LEDs until the disk is replaced.

Comment: @user121391 *Personally I have seen more destroyed/corrupt files than broken hard drives,*  [Linux background](http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_2_6_33#head-3c0fcd3c11814268252fcf6312feb6e953264011)?

Comment: No, still hardware-related, but that is a bit off topic here. My point is: both ZFS and HW RAID protect you from a shared amount of problems (like a failed disk), but ZFS also protects you from additional problems (like bit flips), but you lose some performance in some cases (like with RAID5/6). If you combine them both, you get the features AND lose the performance, so there is no incentive to do it in my opinion. Therefore I would only suggest it if you don't have any other choice (hardware not under your direct control) or in special cases (RAID6+1 for example does not exist in ZFS).

Comment: *"3 copies on two drives. IIRC you can configure that"* Yes and no. You are probably thinking of the `copies` file system attribute. http://linux.die.net/man/8/zfs That applies above and beyond vdev redundancy, so if you have a three-way mirror and set copies=2 you effectively get six copies of the data. raidzN makes the calculations more complicated but the same principle apply.

Comment: Thank you. I vaguely remembered 'something' but you nicely explained it.